# Google-Drive-API File not found using FORM_ID

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-forms-api

I'm a novice Python hobbyist programmer who is trying to automate some vocabulary tests for my students. Everything in the below code works except for sharing it with the list of emails. I know for a fact that the Drive ID is the same as the Forms ID as I have manually checked with testing. I'm able to add all of the questions in the script using `FORM_ID`, but I'm not able to set permissions for some reason with the same `FORM_ID`. I always get the below error. I have also tried authenticating with the same email that created the Google Project, but I get the same error, so I don't think it's related to Google Drive permissions for the authenticating email. I have spent so much time on this error, please help.

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FORM_ID/permissions?alt=json returned "File not found: FORM_ID.". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: FORM_ID.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'fileId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

FULL CODE

```
from __future__ import print_function
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time

def share_form_with_emails(service_account_file, form_id, emails):
    SCOPES_DRIVE = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=SCOPES_DRIVE)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

def share_form(attempt):
    if attempt > 2:
        print("Failed to share the form after 5 attempts.")
        return

    try:
        for email in emails:
            user_permission = {
                'type': 'user',
                'role': 'reader', # sufficient to submit and view the form
                'emailAddress': email
            }
            drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=form_id, body=user_permission).execute()

        print(f'Successfully shared form with {len(emails)} email addresses.')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
        if "File not found" in str(error):
            print(f"Attempt {attempt}: Retrying in {2 ** attempt} seconds...")
            time.sleep(2 ** attempt)
            share_form(attempt + 1)
        else:
            return None

share_form(attempt=1)

def __main__():
    import pandas as pd
    from apiclient import discovery
    from httplib2 import Http
    from oauth2client import client, file, tools

EMAILS = ['blah.blah@gmail.com']
SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body"
DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = r'service_account_keys.json'

store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = None
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(r'credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

form_service = discovery.build('forms', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(
    Http()), discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC, static_discovery=False)

file_name = r'output.xlsx'
dfs = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
for df in dfs:
    if df == 'U2W2' or df == 'U2W3': # TODO: Update this each time to avoid duplicates
        print(f"Setting up Spelling Test: {df}")
        name_title = f"Spelling Test: {df}"
        class_name = 'Green Bears'
        # TODO: Figure out how to share this automatically with list of emails or something
        NEW_FORM = {
            "info": {
                "title": name_title,
                "documentTitle": name_title,
            }
        }
        result = form_service.forms().create(body=NEW_FORM).execute() # Create the new spelling test form
        FORM_ID = result['formId']
        print("FORM_ID", FORM_ID)
        share_form_with_emails(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, FORM_ID, EMAILS) # Share the newly created forms
        NEW_FORM_EDITED_INFO = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "updateFormInfo": {
                        "info": {
                            "title": name_title,
                            "description": f"Type the correct word for the given definition. Good luck, {class_name}!",
                        },
                        "updateMask": "*",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        NEW_FORM_EDITED_SETTINGS = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "updateSettings": {
                        "settings": {
                            "quizSettings": {
                                "isQuiz": True
                            }
                        },
                        "updateMask": "*",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        print(f"-- Setting up Form Info: {df}")
        form_service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=result["formId"], body=NEW_FORM_EDITED_INFO).execute()  # Update form info
        print(f"-- Setting up Form Settings: {df}")
        form_service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=result["formId"], body=NEW_FORM_EDITED_SETTINGS).execute()  # Update form settings
        # Add definition questions
        for index, row in dfs[df].iterrows(): # Iterate over each row as each row is a spelling test question
            print(f"---- Adding question {index + 1} / 20")
            NEW_QUESTION = {
                "requests": [{
                    "createItem": {
                        "item": {
                            "title": f": {dfs[df]['DEFINITION'][index]}",
                            "questionItem": {
                                "question": {
                                    "required": False, # Students don't have to answer any of the questions
                                    "textQuestion": { # Create text question
                                        "paragraph": False # False means short text
                                    },
                                    "grading": {
                                        "pointValue": 1,
                                        "correctAnswers": {
                                            "answers": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": dfs[df]['WORD'][index].lower()
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": dfs[df]['WORD'][index].upper()
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": dfs[df]['WORD'][index].title()
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "index": index
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
            question_setting = form_service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=result["formId"], body=NEW_QUESTION).execute() # Add the question
        # Add paragraph questions
        for i in range(5):
            print(f"---- Adding sentence question {i + 1} / 5")
            NEW_QUESTION_SENTENCE = {
                "requests": [{
                    "createItem": {
                        "item": {
                            "title": "Create an original sentence using any of the above vocabulary words.",
                            "questionItem": {
                                "question": {
                                    "required": False, # Students don't have to answer any of the questions
                                    "textQuestion": { # Create text question
                                        "paragraph": True # False means short text
                                    },
                                    "grading": {
                                        "pointValue": 1,
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "index": i + 20
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
            question_setting = form_service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=result["formId"], body=NEW_QUESTION_SENTENCE).execute() # Add the question
print("\n\n ~~~~~ FINISHED ~~~~~ \n\n")

__main__()
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FORM_ID/permissions` that you are trying to access requires `Authorization` and hence you need to also pass a valid `bearer token` to access the same.

Please check the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) for the `Permissions API`. You will find more information there. Also, please check if the parameter `&alt=json` is supported or not.